# Equivilant Haskell list comprehensions in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

The following [List Comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension) in [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)):

```
(i, 1) | i <- [7,7,7,8,8,8,2,2,1,1]
```

Will output the following tuples:

> [(7,1),(7,1),(7,1),(8,1),(8,1),(8,1),(2,1),(2,1),(1,1),(1,1)]

What would be the equivalent code in Isabelle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[(i, 1) . i <- [7,7,7,8,8,8,2,2,1,1]]
```

which will be automatically translated to

```
map (λi. (i, 1)) [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```